# Do we really need to [contribute]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Tag [contribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contribute) has no tag wiki and currently 28 questions.

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?

The tag does not contribute to questions in any meaningful way. It is ambiguous because some questions are asking about general contributions to open source projects and some how to do something in Git while contributing code. It was also used for some opinion-based and off-topic questions, asking for best projects for contribution or similar.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. Some questions tagged are asking about [adobe-contribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-contribute) software, some about contributing to open source, and some about contributing to something else. Some just use it without any meaningful reason at all.

Comment: This tag should be contributed to Trogdor's pile of ashes.

Comment: My first thought was "How could fundraising even be on-topic for SO?"

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of a catch-all tag without any definitive meaning in any context. Since it is under 50 questions, it can be burnt on the spot even without the discussion, but something tells me the outcome will be unanimous regardless. Also, we have [Web Apps Stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) for questions about issues with GitHub (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991477/new-contributor-is-not-shown-in-public-repository))

Answer (score 35):

I agree with this request. This tag adds absolutely nothing of value to any of the questions.

There are quite a few questions that can be closed and deleted as being off-topic entirely, and all of the rest of the questions can simply do without the tag - there's not even any need to select new tags or create a new, less ambiguous tag.

<sub>Also worth noting - this is eligible for abbreviated burnination.</sub>